# Lenovo Tab P11 erased recovery mode, need to hard reset with computer

Tags: recovery-mode, factory-reset, fastboot, lenovo

I erased recovery_a and recovery_b, Unnofficial TWRP doesn't work. need a recovery that works. Won't boot into twrp and need a hard reset. Can't access OS but fastboot works.
HELP!

Comment: I would use the internal name of the tablet (for Lenovo usually something like TB?????) and check if you can find a download of the original recovery.

Comment: I found an unofficial TWRP Recovery image, but I have already tried to flash it.

Comment: stock recovery is restored automatically. depending on what you mean with *"can't access OS"* it may required to flash stock ROM

Comment: Recovery has been erased and userdata has been erased. can't access OS

Comment: I can access fastboot and test modes. Recovery mode has been erased via computer command and The actual Android system cannot boot.

Comment: fastboot: error: Cannot generate image for userdata

Comment: How do I flash stock ROM of Lenovo J606F? What commands and what image file?

Comment: booted to fastboot and ran fastboot format:ext4 userdata in cmd. But then I powered it on and it rebooted into FFBM Mode.

Comment: I don't know what FFBM mode is but guess you can leave it by vol + pwr combination for fastboot mode. stock ROM can downloaded [here](https://romprovider.com/lenovo-tab-p11-tb-j606f-firmware-download)

Comment: from what I have read I think FFBM mode is Qualcomm DIAG 901D mode used for [NV_items_reader_writer](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/4356451) (yet another flash method) but [LMSA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/4348911) is afaik official flash tool

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself in a situation where you follow the guide at https://unofficialtwrp.com/twrp-3-4-2-root-lenovo-tb-j606f/
only to find your Lenovo Android Device in a fastboot-only state, please use Lenovo rescue and smart assistant to flash stock recovery and the stock Android image to factory reset the tablet.

You can download it at
https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds101291